Chrome extension causing "flickering" on videos when using chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()
I created a firefox add-on/extension that more or less detects commercials on all streaming services by screenshotting a single pixel of the video every second to check if it is the color of the the channel logo, thus indicating it isn't a commercial. That works all fine and dandy, but when I try to port it over to chrome, chrome doesn't support the rect property inside the image details parameter for chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(). For firefox, this allows me to only take a screenshot of only the single pixel I need, but since chrome doesn't support it, I need to capture the entire visible page. Wasteful, but I figured later I could draw just the single pixel of screenshot to grab the color of the pixel that I need. Where I am running into an issue is almost every time I run chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(), the video on the page flickers by dimming the video and/or shifting the colors for a split second. Without any other code and running this from the background.js script targeting a page with a video playing or paused, I am getting the flickering.
function startTakingScreenshots() {
    intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
            chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab();
        });
    }, 1000);
}

I have tried both png and jpeg formats for the screenshot, as well as lower image quality. I can't just draw the video to an image because it needs to work on all streaming services and most are EME protected.
Does anybody happen to know if there is either a workaround to only capture a specific area using chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab() in chrome or if not, how to stop or reduce the flickering?

The only workaround is chrome.debugger API (example), but it shows a warning on top when used. The area is specified via clip, see the documentation.
